# Resync forks of Git-Repo with changed project structure

Tags: git

Imagine having a git-repo (call it *old-repo*) of a project. At one point it got forked as *next-gen*. In *next-gen* someone refactored the project structure widely (rename folders and files according to some standard and such). Those led to some changes in the code as well.

Unfortunately the development on the old branch (which should have been abandoned) continued because they needed some security patches and what else.

Now at one point we want to port the changes from *old-repo* to *next-gen* one time, so *old-repo* can be archived finally.

I can think of three approaches:

**Approach I:**

- Make a diff with meld or such, copy all changes manually.

Disadvantages:

- Loss of all commit messages which where done to *old-branch* after the initial fork.
- Likeliness to forget something

**Approach II:**

- in *next-gen* restore old project structure
- Make *old-repo* be a remote of *next-gen*
- pull & merge
- remove remote
- restore new project structure

Disadvantages:

- If the changes of the project structure are more complex than just rename one or two folders, it's quite an effort to change the project structure twice.

**Approach III:**

- export all commits in *old-repo* after the initial form as patch-file
- search/replace paths ins patch-file
- apply to *next-gen*

Disadvantages:

- Will it even work? Never tried out.

What might be the best? Any thoughts or other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We once faced a similar issue. Our solution is to write a patch converter.

The patch is created by `git format-patch` so that the commit info like the authorship and the commit message can be preserved. The converter replaces the paths in the patch with their counterparts in the new repository.

Suppose the old repository structure is like

```
.
└── a
    └── a.txt
```

And the new repository structure is like

```
.
└── aa
    └── a.txt
```

A patch of a commit in the old repository is like this, appending a new line to `a/a.txt`.

```
From e9d29ded75f26d37ece9b9084bd15598b4f02fe8 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: ElpieKay <ElpieKay@foo.com>
Date: Thu, 9 Jun 2022 16:56:15 +0800
Subject: [PATCH] hello a

---
 a/a.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

diff --git a/a/a.txt b/a/a.txt
index e69de29..ce01362 100644
--- a/a/a.txt
+++ b/a/a.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello
--
2.33.0.windows.1
```

In this example the converter replaces `a/a.txt` in the lines that start with `diff --git` , `--- a/` and `+++ b/`, with `aa/a.txt`.

```
From e9d29ded75f26d37ece9b9084bd15598b4f02fe8 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: ElpieKay <ElpieKay@foo.com>
Date: Thu, 9 Jun 2022 16:56:15 +0800
Subject: [PATCH] hello a

---
 a/a.txt | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

diff --git a/aa/a.txt b/aa/a.txt
index e69de29..ce01362 100644
--- a/aa/a.txt
+++ b/aa/a.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+hello
--
2.33.0.windows.1
```

Then we can use `git am` to apply the converted patch in the new repository.

Comment: This is basically my approach III. Good to know that you made good experienced with it!

Comment: @Paflow several months after I wrote the answer, I learned that `git am` has options to do the job. Taking the patch in my answer for example, we can use `git am -p2 --directory=aa $patchpath` to apply the patch. However, it's a bit hard for most developers to use these tricky options. They are familiar with basic commands. We just keep the patch converter so that they can use the converted patch without worrying about these extra options.

Comment: Woot thank you for your comment! It was a one time action in my case, but next time I know better!